# How can a docker container get full access to a windows share without mounting the share in the host OS?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm using docker on linux and I want to allow my containers to have full access to a windows share (named myshare with appropriate permissions set) that has the following structure:

```
d:\myshare
       foo
       bar
```

As a test, I've verified that putting the following in `/etc/fstab` will create a mount that allows me to RW to the windows share.

```
//172.16.68.6/myshare  /home/me/foo  cifs username=myuser,password=mypass,domain=172.16.68.6,uid=1000
```

Instead of using `/etc/fstab` I'd like to be able to create a volume in docker so that I can do something like the following in my docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - /myshare/foo:/foo
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create one volume then just append the directory name (like I did above with `foo`) so I don't have to create multiple volumes.  But so far I can't even create a mount on the docker host that connects to the windows share.  I wouldn't even know how to "peek" inside of the volume.  I've tried using portainer, but it tells me the volume isn't being used.

How can I create this volume and consume it (preferably in docker-compose)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to use a docker volume plugin.https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/

Preferably, one already exists.  Google it, find it, and follow its instructions.  You should be able to do it.  Check out https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/ for possible candidates.

Alternatively you can write your own docker volume plugin.  Be sure to publish it for the benefit ot others.  This will require a considerable amount of skill, so it might not be practical.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my docker-compose.yml that is working for me. You must use the ip address in the path:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - logs:/mnt/logs

volumes:
  spark_logs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      device: "//10.1.1.7/path/prd/sist/log"
      o: username=${USER},password=${PASS},file_mode=0444,dir_mode=0444
```